# Web app that sends a password x hours after a request is made

Tags: passwords, password-protection, change-password

I am looking for a specific app that has a really specific feature.

Please tell me if this feature already exists on dashlane or 1password.

**Context  :** 
I have a software that prevents me from accessing web sites where i waste my time.

**Problem :** 
When I feel tempted to waste my time, I access the software and I unlock the websites

**Direct consequence :** 
I waste my time again.

**What I am not allowed to do solve the problem** :
Count on my discipline. If you suggest me to count on my discipline to solve the problem, you will be out of scope.

**Opportunity :** 
If the app existed, my problem would be solved :

**Description of the app :**

It's an app that sends an email with specific content x hours after a request is sent

To understand better what I mean, here is a use case :

**Use case :**

I create a really long password to access the software that blocks websites.
I send an email where the following informations are present : 
1°) the password : let's call it : "password"
2°) The time to wait after a request is made : let's say 24 hours
3°) The trigger necessary to send the specific password : let's say : website

When the mail is sent, I delete the email so that the password is no longer accessible from me easily.
I receive a notification from this app that tells me :
Ok, we received your request for "website".

2 months after, I want to add a website that I want to block, or I want to access a website again.

I then send the following email to the correct email address with the following content :
"website"

(If I wanted to cancel my request 24 hours, I would just send :"website stop")
I wait 24 hours and I receive the password.
I do the desired modification.
I delete permanently the email where the password is present.

I am now able to avoid being tempted wasting my time.

It's kind of a "temptation buffer".

Do you know any web app or email server that does that ?

It's not necessary to use email to solve the problem, i can also login to a web app.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer, but if you'd consider a different approach ... perhaps a browser add-on that limits site access to X minutes per day, such as [StayFocusd](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stayfocusd/laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji)?

Comment: Thanks a lot, i know this extension. The problem is that you can use safari or mozilla to browse.

Comment: If you find this question relevant, could you upvote it please ?